# How to apply a trained machine learning model of images to a video?

Tags: image, video, model, generative-adversarial-network, pre-trained-model

I trained an Image-To-Image GAN Model (an image enhancement model) and I have my .pt file. I was wondering how could I apply it to a video. Being it a sequence of frames I think it's possible to do it but i don't know how!

Thank you for anyone who will help me